# Cart system made in php

Tags: php, composer-php

So I keep getting this error from my app.php and have no clue whats going on. I am following a tutorial about how to make a shop cart in php. I will leave the code and error text and maybe you guys have an idea.

Error text :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Cart\App' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\cart\bootstrap\app.php:11 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\cart\public\index.php(3): require() #1 {main} thrown
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\cart\bootstrap\app.php on line 11

To save you some time the error is coming from $app = new App;

Code :

```
<?php

use Cart\App;
use Slim\Views\Twig;
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

session_start();

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new App;

$container = $app->getContainer();

$capsule = new Capsule;
$capsule->addConnection([
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'database' => 'cart',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => ''
]);

$capsule->setAsGlobal();
$capsule->bootEloquent();

Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('MERCHANT_ID');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('PUBLIC_KEY');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('PRIVATE_KEY');

require __DIR__ . '/../app/routes.php';

$app->add(new \Cart\Middleware\ValidationErrorsMiddleware($container->get(Twig::class)));
$app->add(new \Cart\Middleware\OldInputMiddleware($container->get(Twig::class)));
```

Composer :

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "^3.0",
        "slim/twig-view": "^2.4",
        "php-di/slim-bridge": "^2.0",
        "illuminate/database": "^5.6"
    },
    "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
        "Cart\\": "app"
      }
    }
}
```

App.php :

```
<?php

namespace Cart;

use DI\ContainerBuilder;
use DI\Bridge\Slim\App as DiBridge;

class App extends DIBridge
{
    protected function configureContainer(ContainerBuilder $builder)
    {
        $builder->addDefinitions([
            'settings.displayErrorDetails' => true,
        ]);

        $builder->addDefinitions(__DIR__ . '/container.php');
    }
}
```

Container.php :

```
<?php

use function DI\get;
use Slim\Views\Twig;
use Cart\Basket\Basket;
use Cart\Models\Product;
use Cart\Models\Payment;
use Slim\Views\TwigExtension;
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Cart\Support\Storage\SessionStorage;
use Cart\Support\Storage\Contracts\StorageInterface;
use Cart\Validation\Contracts\ValidatorInterface;
use Cart\Validation\Validator;
use Cart\Models\Order;
use Cart\Models\Customer;
use Cart\Models\Address;

return [
    'router' => get(Slim\Router::class),
    ValidatorInterface::class => function (ContainerInterface $c) {
        return new Validator;
    },
    StorageInterface::class => function (ContainerInterface $c) {
        return new SessionStorage('cart');
    },
    Twig::class => function (ContainerInterface $c) {
        $twig = new Twig(__DIR__ . '/../resources/views', [
            'cache' => false
        ]);

        $twig->addExtension(new TwigExtension(
            $c->get('router'),
            $c->get('request')->getUri()
        ));

        $twig->getEnvironment()->addGlobal('basket', $c->get(Basket::class));

        return $twig;
    },
    Product::class => function (ContainerInterface $c) {
        return new Product;
    },
    Order::class => function (ContainerInterface $c) {
        return new Order;
    },
    Customer::class => function (ContainerInterface $c) {
        return new Customer;
    },
    Address::class => function (ContainerInterface $c) {
        return new Address;
    },
    Payment::class => function (ContainerInterface $c) {
        return new Payment;
    },
    Basket::class => function (ContainerInterface $c) {
        return new Basket(
            $c->get(SessionStorage::class),
            $c->get(Product::class)
        );
    }
];
```

Comment: If you need something else like info of other files please tell me.

Comment: You should share your `composer.json`. And probably content and path of file where you have defined `Cart\App` class.

Comment: now i am sharing them

Comment: And what is the full path of `App.php` file?

Comment: In container.php i guess

Comment: i have put it in

Comment: I mean where this file is located. If file path does not match namespace and autoloader rules, autoloader will not find it. Can you just share your project structure (where is `composer.json`, `App.php`, `vendor` directory and other files mentioned in question)?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/key3vn, http://prntscr.com/key400, http://prntscr.com/key44d

Comment: I have made some screenshots with the file structures

Comment: Btw I am new in composer

Comment: @rob006 do you need something else ?

Comment: Please help me guys i beg of you, I need a lot of help I want to finish it, I stay for 9 hours and cant resolve it. Please help me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have resolved it after 9 hours it was a misspelled Name instead of name i have wrote Nmae, SO FOR EVERYONE WITH THIS PROBLEM CHECK ALL THE NAMES AND CLASSES THAT YOU HAVE TO BE CORRECT THATS THE ONLY SOLUTION

Answer (score 0):

The `use` statements must be AFTER the import of `autoload.php`

Comment: $app = new App; the error has something to do with this

Comment: This is not true.

Comment: what is not true @rob006 ?

Comment: @Zomelock This answer. `use` statements does not trigger autoloading, you can (and should) keep it at the top of file content, before requiring autoloader.

Comment: So the `Cart` namespace maps to `app` folder, right ? And `App.php` is inside this folder ? Does something change if you add trailing slash to the `app` ?

Comment: Maybe you can add some logging inside this `autoload.php` to get an insight what filename exactly it is trying to include when looking for the `Cart\App` class.

Comment: I am new in composer could you tell me how to do it?

Comment: a no nvm, let me see

Comment: or yes tell me how to do it

Comment: The easiest way is by using Sysinternals Process Monitor (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) - it will show all filesystem access and will see where it is looking for that PHP file

Comment: Choose the process name which you want to trace (most probably the Apache - or if unsure, you can trace all running processes) and then use the icons in the toolbar to activate the tracing of File System activity. The run your PHP application, it will produce the error, you will stop tracing (by pressing Ctrl + E) and then look through the trace log to see where and which file is searched for the `Cart\App` class.

Comment: I am kind of stuck because of the UI, do you have teamviewer so you can see my screen, maybe it helps you ?

Comment: I think thats against the stackoverflow rules, I dont know if it is announce me